# String DAC - Question

Tags: dac

I was reading about String DACs here https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/voltage-mode-r2r-dacs-operation-and-characteristics/

and I saw
[image]

[image]

I**s the highlighed wrong? I mean, if just SW4 was on, shouldn't the output analog voltage be 1/2 Vref**, since there are 4 resistors above SW4 and 4 below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. 
The author probably meant to write

> For example, to produce an analog output equal to V<sub>REF</sub>/4, we only need to turn the switch sw<sub>**2**</sub> on.

Note that with this circuit the output range is 0 to V<sub>REF</sub> × 7/8. You can't get V<sub>REF</sub>.

Comment: Great! I was doubting myself for 15min. Thought there was no hope for me if I messed up a resistive divider haha.